# How can I display total likes per month of an post to the author on Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I want to display total likes a author got on his post on monthly basis in Django. For eg: On january total likes of his post is like 100

```
def total_contents(self):
    total_likes_received = post.objects.filter(author=self.request.user).count()
    return total_likes_received

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['total_contents'] = self.total_contents()
    return context
```

This is my views.py but this code will return total post he posted on the website. I want to return total likes he go on his post per month on Django

```
class blogs(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True, auto_created=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_on = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    time = models.TimeField(auto_now=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='likes', blank=True)
    liked = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    like_count = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)
    post = models.TextField(max_length=200 )
```

Comment: I think the current model design can get you blogs that were created on monthly basis. But not the likes count of the Blogs filtered by months. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You have to create a new model which can store likes data based on time and post.

Comment: I want to get total views of an post that an author got and display it on his profile page